# Country listing: how to select x countries and insert/update in 1 field

Tags: php

At this time I have **a list of european countries**. Customers can **select several countries** where they want to show there **advertisements**.
At this moment every country has his own country field and the can select via an checkbox.

> Is it possible to save and the checked countries into 1 field? The update is via a Jquery script

Here how I show it now:

```
$targetnl   = ($result->NL  == 1) ? "checked" : '';
$targetde   = ($result->DE  == 1) ? "checked" : '';
$targetbe   = ($result->BE  == 1) ? "checked" : '';
$targetfr   = ($result->FR  == 1) ? "checked" : '';

if($result->NL  == 1) $cntr[] = ' NL ';
if($result->DE  == 1) $cntr[] = "DE ";
if($result->BE  == 1) $cntr[] = "BE ";
if($result->FR  == 1) $cntr[] = "FR ";

$content .= '
<div class="form-field"><div class="checkbox-companion-wide">
<span class="title">'. __('Advertisement Target Countries:', 'agent-plugin').'</span><br>

<input class="checkbox_field" type="checkbox" name="NL"  data-pk="'.$uid.'" value="'.(($result->NL ==1) ? 0 : 1 ).'" '.$targetnl.'  />
<label>'. __('Netherlands', 'agent-plugin').'</label><i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i>

<input class="checkbox_field" type="checkbox" name="DE"  data-pk="'.$uid.'" value="'.(($result->DE ==1) ? 0 : 1 ).'" '.$targetde.'  />
<label>'. __('Germany', 'agent-plugin').'</label><i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i>

<input class="checkbox_field" type="checkbox" name="BE"  data-pk="'.$uid.'" value="'.(($result->BE ==1) ? 0 : 1 ).'" '.$targetbe.' />
<label>'. __('Belgium', 'agent-plugin').'</label><i class="fa fa-check" style="display:none;"></i>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp

Comment: Hi, not the solution for me. Also miss the part how to save/update the select into 1 field.